# Fatal error: Class 'string' not found in paypal sdk

Tags: php, paypal

I am using the paypal sdk for adaptive payments(new release). On local server everything works fine but once i move it to the other server it says.

```
Fatal error: Class 'string' not found in "path/payment/lib/PPMessage.php" on line 103
```

The php version on both the servers are same. I tried giving relative path etc but nothing seems to be working.

Please Help! Thanks.

Comment: Experiences like this are why I developed [my own PHP class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/download-angell-eye-php-class-library-for-paypal) and have been maintaining it for years.  It's much more complete than their own and doesn't have issues like this.  I'd recommend you take a look at it.  I think you'll like what you see.  Makes things very simple for you.

Answer (score 0):

i created a issue on github

https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-php/issues/92#issuecomment-256091144

solution was this:
change line 75 of PPMessage.php

change this line:
https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-php/blob/master/lib/PayPal/Core/PPMessage.php#L75

```
  if (!$this->isBuiltInType($type)) {
    $type = PPUtils::propertyType($this, $property);
    if (!class_exists($type)) {
      trigger_error("Class $type not found.", E_USER_NOTICE);
      continue; // just ignore
    }
  }
```